# Redirect to 404 page does not work correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react app with some routes using react-router-dom. I described my routes correctly then I wrote that when url is /**/ redirect to 404 page ;
this is my routes :

```js
    <Router>
      <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />

         // my other routes
    
         <Route path="/404" component={NotFoundPage} />
         <Redirect from="/**/" to="/404" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

when I go to other pages they shows correctly without any problem and when I write a wrong url in my browser it redirects to /404 address and correctly works but when I want to go to my homepage with "/" url address it redirects me to "/404" url; I don't know where is my problem

Answer (score 1):

```
    <Router>
      <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
       <Route path="/404" component={NotFoundPage} />

       // other routes

       <Redirect to="/404" />
      </Switch>
   </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason "/" url is redirecting to "/404" url is because of this route:

```
<Redirect from="/**/" to="/404" />
```

For handling 404 routes, simply write your routes like this:

```
<Router>
      <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />

         // other routes

         <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , I tried your solution but not found component shows in all pages I don't know why

Comment: Are you sure? The not found route must be written at the end only... It works fine on my system.

Comment: Also all your routes must be enclosed in Switch, otherwise for every route it will show 404 page @N.SH

Comment: For your reference, you can follow this [article](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/react-router-not-found-component) too.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to redirect everything that don't match you should omit `from` prop, so you should write it at the bottom of your `Switch` like this:

```
<Redirect to="/404" />
```

It works with version ^5